# Trying to zip files in one directory only

Tags: python, zip

I have the path /home/mine/new that contains files and sub directories. I want to zip the files that are in that path only (in the 'new' path), so that my zipped folder contains `/new/file1`, `new/file2`, etc.

I tried this :

```
import zipfile
import os,glob


def zipfunc(path, myzip):
    for path,dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if  os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)):
                    myzip.write(os.path.join(os.path.basename(path), file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path=r'/home/ggous/new'
    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('myzipped.zip', 'w')
    zipfunc(path,myzip)
    myzip.close()
```

But it gives me an error
    No such file or directory new/file.doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `os.path.basename` on the path variable.  That means that if you're trying to zip the file `new/dir1/file1`, you drop the `new/` part of the path and end up with `dir1/file1`, which isn't a valid path relative to your current directory.

If you simply remove the call to `os.path.basename` it will zip up the files correctly:

```
myzip.write(os.path.join(path, file))
```

...although this may not be what you want in the zipfile in terms of paths.  If you start your `os.walk` from inside the top level directory you may get what you want:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new')
    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('myzipped.zip', 'w')

    # Change into the top level directory.
    os.chdir(path)

    zipfunc('.',myzip)
    myzip.close()
```

Given a hierarchy like this:

```
/home/lars/new
  file1
  file2
  dir1/
    file1
    file2
    file3
```

This creates a zipfile that looks like this:

```
Archive:  myzipped.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       29  11-02-2011 09:14   file1
       29  11-02-2011 09:14   file2
       29  11-02-2011 09:14   dir1/file3
       29  11-02-2011 09:14   dir1/file1
       29  11-02-2011 09:14   dir1/file2
---------                     -------
      145                     5 files
```

If you actual goal is to only zip up files in the top level and *not* descend into any subdirectories, then you don't really need `os.walk`.  You can just use `os.listdir` instead, and `os.path.isfile` to make sure you're dealing with files and not subdirectories.

Comment: :It works great ,but as you say above i don't want the subfolders and theri files in 'new'.I am using the isfile method but still the same result.

Comment: Ok, i used os.listdir and now it's ok!.If i want in the zipfile to show me not only the files but also the folder.For ex. : /new/file1 ,/new/file2 ,how can i add it?Because i am trying basename but it dosen't work.

Comment: If you want to include the parent path, then don't `os.chdir()` into the directory, but *do* continue to use `os.listdir()` and `os.path.join()`.

Comment: :@larsks:I tried it but it creates a zipfile which contains the same zipfile and when i try to open it it gives'error canot open file as archive'

Answer (score 0):

That's because `os.walk` will descend into subdirectories (and your path joining logic doesn't handle that correctly). If you don't want to recurse into subdirs, then use `glob.glob` instead of `os.walk`:

```
from os import path
import os

directory = r'/home/ggous/new'
for f in os.listdir(directory):
     if path.isfile(f):
         zipfile.write(os.path.basename(f), f)
```

Comment: Hello,this gives me an error 'module object is not callable' in the line 'for f in glob..'

Comment: @George: then you haven't copied the `import glob` line correctly. You can also use `os.listdir`, btw.

Comment: @George: but not with `from glob import glob`, I presume.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be an issue with `zipfile.ZipFile.write()` requiring an absolute path, as opposed to a relative or incomplete one. Try making sure that the path is absolute before zipping the file it points to:

```
def zipfunc(path, myzip):
    for path,dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                curpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, file))
                if  os.path.isfile(curpath):
                    myzip.write(curpath)
```

Comment: The above takes all the subdirectories and their files.I only want the files that are in the 'new' folder.